# Fade in/out background image on hover

Tags: javascript, css

Instead of transitions left to right, right to left. How can I make it to fade in fade out, no movements, just opacity fade out, fade in.

http://designshack.net/articles/css/swap-your-pages-background-image-on-navigation-hover/

Comment: would jquery be an option?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the CSS3 properties *opacity* and *transition*

```
.yourClass
{
    opacity: 1;
    transition: all 3s ease;
} 

.yourClass:hover 
{
    opacity: 0;
}
```

An example here :

http://jsfiddle.net/ghBAT/

Comment: can you update your example to like this, but with fade: http://designshack.net/tutorialexamples/navpics/index.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are ok with jquery - have a look at [`.fadeIn()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/)

```
<div id="clickme">
  Click here
</div>
<img id="book" src="book.png" alt="" width="100" height="123">

// With the element initially hidden, we can show it slowly:
$( "#clickme" ).click(function() {
  $( "#book" ).fadeIn( "slow", function() {
    // Animation complete
  });
});
```

Comment: can you please provide example like this? but with fade? http://designshack.net/tutorialexamples/navpics/index.html